# Grouping MySQL view in a sequence of rolling dates

Tags: mysql, sql-view

I've got two tables:

```
Table Transmission
------------------------------
Id  GroupID Amount Timestamp
1   1       5      2015-05-20 00:00:00
2   1       4      2015-05-19 00:00:00
3   1       10      2015-04-20 00:00:00
4   1       7      2015-04-19 00:00:00
5   1       9      2015-03-20 00:00:00
6   1       2      2015-03-18 00:00:00


Table Group
---------
Id DateCreated BillStart  BillStop
1  2015-03-15  2015-05-15 2015-06-14
```

BillStart and BillStop have a trigger on them that runs daily, if the current Date is greater than BillStop, both BillStart/BillStop increase by a month (so these are effectively the current range we are looking at).

I already have a SQL view that can sum up a range of the transmission entries where the timestamp is between BillStart and BillStop, what I am looking to do is have another view that would effectively hold the sums of transmissions of past months. i.e. if a BillStart/BillStop goes from 2015-05-15 to 2015-06-14, then the view would know to group past transmissions from the ranges of 2015-4-15 to 20-15-14, 2015-3-15 to 2015-4-14, and so on, up until the last range containing the groups creation date.

Ideally the view would look like

```
-------------------------------------
GroupId   Sum   BillStart   BillStop
1         9     2015-05-15  2015-06-14
1         17     2015-04-15  2015-05-14
1         11     2015-03-15  2015-04-14
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Another option I was considering was a table for GroupBillRanges that would entail:

```
GroupBillRange
--------------
Id GroupId BillStart   BillStop
1  1       2015-03-15  2015-04-14
2  1       2015-04-15  2015-05-14
3  1       2015-05-15  2015-06-14
```

And this would be added when each bill range gets updated by the month.  With this I would just be able to match all `Transmission.GroupId` to `GroupDateRange.GroupId`

Comment: Group is a reserved word. This makes it a poor choice for a table identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would need to create the "GroupBillRange" table.  Otherwise you lose any record of what the Bill Start/Stop dates were on the old groups.  (Sure, you could assume that they are always from the 15th to the 14th. But the one time that they are not, you will have problems.)  Once you do that, a query like the following should give you what you're looking for, I believe.  (Oh, and you have this question tagged as both SQL Server and MySQL.  So I created this script on SQL Server 2008 r2.)

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Transmission TABLE (
  ID int,
  GroupID int,
  Amount int,
  TransmissionDate SmallDateTime );

INSERT @Transmission VALUES (1, 1, 5,'2015/05/20');
INSERT @Transmission VALUES (2, 1, 4,'2015/05/19');
INSERT @Transmission VALUES (3, 1,10,'2015/04/20');
INSERT @Transmission VALUES (4, 1, 7,'2015/04/19');
INSERT @Transmission VALUES (5, 1, 9,'2015/03/20');
INSERT @Transmission VALUES (6, 1, 2,'2015/03/18');

DECLARE @TableGroupRange TABLE (
  ID int,
  GroupID int,
  BillStart SmallDateTime,
  BillStop SmallDateTime );

INSERT @TableGroupRange VALUES (1, 1, '2015/03/15', '2015/04/14' )
INSERT @TableGroupRange VALUES (2, 1, '2015/04/15', '2015/05/14' )
INSERT @TableGroupRange VALUES (3, 1, '2015/05/15', '2015/06/14' )

SET NOCOUNT OFF;

SELECT      TG.GroupID, SUM(T.Amount) as SumAmount, TG.BillStart, TG.BillStop
FROM        @TableGroupRange TG
LEFT JOIN   @Transmission T ON T.GroupID = TG.GroupID AND T.TransmissionDate BETWEEN TG.BillStart AND TG.BillStop
GROUP BY    TG.GroupID, TG.BillStart, TG.BillStop
ORDER BY    TG.GroupID, TG.BillStart, TG.BillStop
```

Comment: I removed the SQL-Server tag from the question as the title specifically stated MySQL